# How to bring a marker popup to the front in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, popup, openlayers

I have a popup that I'm declaring like so in OpenLayers:

```
var feature = new O[penLayers.Feature(markers, lonLat);
feature.popupClass = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud, {
    'autoSize': true;
    'maxSize': new OpenLayers.Size(500, 300)
});
```

The issue is that the multiple popups on my map are being created with consecutive z-indexes, so the popups will always be shown in the order the markers were added, with the popup of the most recent marker always being on top.

Is there a way to change it so that the most recently-clicked marker popup is on top, instead of that of the most recently-added marker?  I've tried manually changing the z-index in firebug (as a test) but it doesn't bring it to the front.  I'd rather avoid deleting and remaking the popup or marker, but it seems to be the only solution I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to reliably change the z-index and have it work, but I was able to solve my problem by completely removing and then creating a new clone of the map marker when I wanted it in the front.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to make the trick of the `zindex` like this

```
clientesLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("PuntosVentas");


feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(vectorFatri.puntos[index][0],vectorFatri.puntos[index][1]),
    {description: '<div><div class="popup_title"><h4>'+vectorFatri.imei+'</h4></div><div class="popup_content">'+vectorFatri.fecha[index]+'</div></div>'} ,
    {
        strokeColor: "#00FF00",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF5500",
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        pointRadius: 6,
        pointerEvents: "visiblePainted"
    }
);

controls = {
    selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(clientesLayer, {

        onSelect: function (feature) {
            feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
                    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                    new OpenLayers.Size(300,200),
                    '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.attributes.description+'</div>',
                    null,
                    true,
                    function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
            );
            map.addPopup(feature.popup);
            {# console.log('me seleccionaron');#}

            //jquery trick to make the popup front of everything
            $(".olPopup").css("z-index", 10000)

            {# setTimeout(function(){$(".olPopup").css("z-index", 10000);}, 2000);#}
        },

        onUnselect: function (feature) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
        }
    })
}

map.addControl(controls['selector']);
controls['selector'].activate();
clientesLayer.addFeatures(feature);
```

Answer (score 0):

call `ms.setZIndex(100000);` where `ms` is the container of the marker (an instance of `OpenLayers.Layer.Markers`);